# how to use Landscape mode in android 4.2

Tags: android, landscape

I am using android 4.2 when i am trying to run my program it's working only in portrait mode. Not displaying anything in landscape mode.

I have also used 
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-portrait-amp-landscape-differeent-layouts

http://android.programmerguru.com/android-landscape-layout-example/

but still no success.

Steps i followed

1. created one more folder with layout-land and keep in same where layout is present.
2. copied main.xml from layout and pasted in layout-land folder.
3. added one more button in layout-land -> main.xml.
4. running in my android device but it's showing only in portrait mode.

please tell where i made mistake ?

Comment: Have you check the activity specific properties in manifest file for orientation support ? You can specify the orientation modes in manifest file for specific activities.

Comment: tried with android:screenOrientation="landscape" but no success

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both XML files present in two different folders(namely layout and layout-land) have same name.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your manifest to open activity in Landscape mode

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.newdatabase.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
created one more folder with layout-land and keep in same where layout is present.
copied main.xml from layout and pasted in layout-land folder.
added one more button in layout-land -> main.xml.
running in my android device but it's showing only in portrait mode.
```

You did it wrong. `layout-land` should only be used if your landscape layout is **different** in landscape from what layout is is considered "default" one (which is the one in `layout` folder). If you do not need different layout, then just keep one file in `layout` folder and it will be used in either portrait or landscape mode.

You may also want to check your Manifest file and check if you by any chance  do not enforce portrait there. ALso "shows nothing" is quite odd - I'd rather bet that your default layout is rendered incorrectly in landscape mode rather than android failed to show anything.

Comment: I have changed main.xml in Landscape mode. I have taken linear layout in landscape mode and relative layout in portrait mode.